# Do I have to specify handles to be inherited with PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST when using CreateProcess in threads?

Tags: winapi, pipe, handle, createprocess

I'm writing a program that spawns multiple child processes simultaneously and communicates to each of them by redirecting their stdin/stdout to anonymous pipes (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)).

This is my actual code adapted from above example:

```cpp
    HANDLE h_child_stdout_r = NULL;
    HANDLE h_child_stdout_w = NULL;
    HANDLE h_child_stdin_r = NULL;
    HANDLE h_child_stdin_w = NULL;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr; 
    BOOL bSuccess = TRUE; 
 
    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
    bSuccess &= CreatePipe(&h_child_stdout_r, &h_child_stdout_w, &saAttr, 0);

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
    bSuccess &= SetHandleInformation(h_child_stdout_r, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 
    bSuccess &= CreatePipe(&h_child_stdin_r, &h_child_stdin_w, &saAttr, 0);

    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 
    bSuccess &= SetHandleInformation(h_child_stdin_w, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    if(!bSuccess)
    {
        throw dlg_exception("Failed to create child process handles");
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo; 
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
  
    ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );
    ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
 
    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    siStartInfo.hStdError = h_child_stdout_w;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = h_child_stdout_w;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = h_child_stdin_r;

    DWORD processFlags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;

    // Create the child process. 
    bSuccess = CreateProcess(
        const_cast<wchar_t *>(utf8::widen(exeName).c_str()),        // application name
        const_cast<wchar_t *>(utf8::widen(cmd).c_str()),           // command line
        NULL,          // process security attributes 
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
        processFlags,  // creation flags 
        NULL,          // use parent's environment 
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
        &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 
   
    // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
    if (!bSuccess) 
    {
        string msg = "Create process failed with error code ";
        msg.append( std::to_string(GetLastError()) );
        throw dlg_exception(msg.c_str());
    }

    // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
    // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
    // of the child process, for example. 
    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
      
    // Close handles to the stdin and stdout pipes no longer needed by the child process.
    // If they are not explicitly closed, there is no way to recognize that the child process has ended.
    CloseHandle(h_child_stdout_w);
    CloseHandle(h_child_stdin_r);
```

The above function will be called from multiple threads that are responsible for creating child processes and reading their output.

Everything works as expected but just to make sure I started searching about thread-safety of `CreateProcess` and I came across [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200306-00/?p=103538) which in short says there will be an issue if multiple calls to `CreateProcess` are made from different threads because then each child process will inherit ALL handles from the parent process.

Now I have two questions:

1- Will this really be an issue for me? Since I am only redirecting the child process's stdin and stdout to the pipe handles, so I'm not sure if there will be a problem even if all the handles are inherited by the child. The child is merely writing to its own stdout and doesn't care about what handles it has inherited right?

2- I tried inspecting the child processes with Sysinternal's Process Explorer but as far as I could tell only two handles were inherited by each child not all of them.

Here's a screenshot of Process Explorer. As you can see the parent process has created 4 child processes. For each process I created, a new pair of handles would appear in parent process's list of handles (I have highlighted the first two):

[image: Process Explorer Screenshot]

As you can see there is four pairs of these, one for each child process.

And for each child process the handle list looks like this:

[image: Process Explorer Screenshot]

After reading the article what I was expecting was that the fourth child process would have all the handles listed because it's supposed to inherit all inheritable handles. But it only has two handles like all other childs.

So I'm wondering if I can get away with my current code without doing the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` which looks complicated and unfun.

Comment: "*the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` which looks complicated and unfun*" - Have you read [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873) and [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130426-00/?p=4543) yet?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I have read both. They have HeapAlloc() and a lot of ifs and things that could go wrong. I don't want to do this unless I know I have to, hence asking this question.

Comment: you don't **have** to, no. But you **should** if you can. Don't expose things that you don't need to. The 1st article I linked to mentions this. You may not always be in control of every little thing. There may be pieces you don't control, or are even aware of, that might create inheritable handles that shouldn't be inherited by your particular child process.